# DataStudio Connexion with Postgres SSL Certificate issus

Tags: database, postgresql, openssl, looker-studio, forestadmin

i'm trying to connect my Postgres DataBase with DataStudio but i don't know where to get the ssl certificate
i followed this tutorial but it don't work for me https://plata.news/blog/integrate-google-data-studio-with-postgres-using-ssl/

[image]

Comment: in tutorial which you have in link there is description how to do everything properly. If you saying "i don't know where to get the ssl certificate" that mean you do not read the tutorial properly

Comment: @noname i followed the tutorial but the certificat that i.ve generated didn't work because i need to add them to the server where postgres is installed, and the probleme is that i can't do that because i don't have the acces to the server via scalegrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution for that you just need to upload the same file for the three certificate and i found the certificat in the scaleGrid platform it's the ca.pem [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only certificate that you need to supply is the server CA certificate.This is only for SSL setup since the certificate is self signed.

Client authentication using certificates is a different scenario and you don't need to specify that since you are using username/password.

Here is a simple set of steps to connect with SSL fwith a few others UI's
https://help.scalegrid.io/docs/postgresql-connecting-to-gui-dbeaver
https://help.scalegrid.io/docs/postgresql-connecting-to-gui-razorsql